# Shopify pop-up - adding checkout button

Tags: popup, shopify

I am trying to add a "`checkout`" button to the standard cart popup that occurs when a customer "`adds to cart`".

I am using the `Shopify` debut theme, but the question would apply to pretty much any `Shopify` theme that has a "`add to cart pop-up`".

It was pretty easy to add the extra code to "cart-popup.liquid", as I copied it over from "`cart-template.liquid`".

The button itself is showing, but it doesn't work.
The other buttons I added, checkout with `Paypal` and `Amazon` checkout all show and also work fine.

Below is the 'donor code'

```
<div class="cart__buttons-container">
  <div class="cart__submit-controls">

    <input type="submit" name="checkout" class="cart__submit btn btn--small-wide" value="{{ 'cart.general.checkout' | t }}">
  </div>

  <div class="cart__error-message-wrapper hide" role="alert" data-cart-error-message-wrapper>
    <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'general.accessibility.error' | t }} </span> {% include 'icon-error' %}
    <span class="cart__error-message" data-cart-error-message></span>
  </div>

  {%- if additional_checkout_buttons -%}
  <div class="additional-checkout-buttons">{{ content_for_additional_checkout_buttons }}</div>
  {%- endif -%}
</div>
```

And this extra code shows the buttons correctly on the popup.

[the buttons all work except for the main one! checkout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnsCq.png)

I think something is missing ... any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: I think the key lies with:  value="{{ 'cart.general.checkout' | t }}">

Comment: I am getting closer but not there yet!  The issue is that I need a link, not a form input.  There needs to be a <a href> to point to the checkout page ...

Comment: @Sean S I saw that you did some similar changes to the Debut theme - would you be able to help with this.  We can pay!